# Which word is for any going-out event?

Tags: word-request

Which word is for any going-out event, i.e. temporarily leaving where one lives for some personal business in another place?
"outgoing" as noun means personal expense. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

An [errand](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/errand) is a short trip to accomplish some bit of personal business, either for yourself or on behalf of someone else.  An errand is short - several minutes up to a couple of hours. You would generally not use this word for an overnight trip. Sometimes the word applies to the items of personal business and is used in the plural, but the idea that you've traveled a short distance to accomplish those things is still included.  Examples:

> Can you spare some time to **run a quick errand** for me?
>
> She's going to the post office **on an errand** for her mother.
>
> I'm taking a longer lunch break than usual because I need to **run a few errands** - drop off my dry cleaning, buy some cat food, and if there's time, I'll take the car through the car wash.

As @StephenS mentioned in the comments, you don't use **errand** for scheduled activities, just for things you do during available time. Going to school or work are things you do on a schedule, so these would not be called errands.

To be honest, I'm not aware of a single word for a trip to work or school - people just say that they are **going to work** or **going to school**.

There are words that are used for a brief trip, whether scheduled or not: **outing** is common; **sortie**, **junket**, and **excursion** are rarer. But all of these have a connotation of something done for entertainment, rather than work or school.

Comment: Does go to school or work count as an errand?

Comment: Usually not - an errand is shorter than you would typically stay at school or work and not usually a daily activity.

Comment: @StephenS - That's a good point, I've expanded the answer.